# React dynamically mutating a state list async problem

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, state

I'm pretty new to React and I'm currently trying to append to a list in my state multiple times. However, the state doesn't seem to be updating and I suspect it could be due to async(?). I would appreciate any pointers :-)

```
this.state = {
    data: []
};

var json = {name: "default", cost:1}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this.setState({ data: [...this.state.data,json] });
    }
```

The above code prints this:

```
[]  
[]
[{name: "default", cost: 1}]
```

edit: more code

```
componentWillMount() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this.setValue(this.props.data[i]);
    }
}

setValue(rowData) {
    let {
        checkbox: checkbox,
        checked: checked,
        data: data,
        name: name,
        headers: headers
    } = this.props;
    var json = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        json[headers[i]] = rowData[i];
    }
    json["checked"] = checked;
    this.setState(prevState => { data: [...prevState.data, json] });
    { console.log(this.getValue()) }
}
```

Comment: you can't read state value just after setState - place `console.log(this.getValue())` in `render`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the functional form of `this.setState()`.

```
this.state = {
    data: []
};

var json = {name: "default", cost:1}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ data: [...prevState.data,json] }));
}
```

More info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've swapped to `this.setState(prevState => { data: [...prevState.data, json] });` but it still doesn't seem to be updating my list. Now it prints `[] [] []`. Seems like the list isn't being updated at all now :-(

Comment: are you logging this with `console.log`? or are you printing it out somewhere?

Comment: I'm logging it with `console.log`, should I not be?

Comment: No, that's okay, but where exactly are you logging it? can you show me the full file code?

Comment: I've added what my functions look like- hopefully this will provide you some more insight

Comment: Ooooh okay, I see. I see two problems there:
First off, the `componentWillMount` method is deprecated because it sometimes isn't called, you should switch it for the safer `componentDidMount` method.
However that's probably not the problem you're facing. The idea of `setState` is that it doesn't update the state immediately, it will do it at some point in the future, and that will trigger a re-render. So if you `console.log` the state from the render method, it will work.

Comment: Alternatively, if you absolutely want to `console.log` from that function, you can pass it as a second argument to `setState` like so: `this.setState(prevState => ({ data: [...prevState.data, json] }), () => console.log(this.getValue()));`
This will trigger the function after the state updates.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! It cleared a lot of things up for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

setState() is asynchronous, so you can't guarantee that it will be updated for the next call to setState().

I would change your code to first create the array with the data and then call setState() when finished. That would look something like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        data.push(this.getValue(this.props.data[i]));
    }
    this.setState({data});
}

getValue(rowData) {
    let {
        checkbox: checkbox,
        checked: checked,
        data: data,
        name: name,
        headers: headers
    } = this.props;
    var json = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        json[headers[i]] = rowData[i];
    }
    json["checked"] = checked;
    return json;
}
```